# How to enable anchor tag on a table row?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

```
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-bordered">
       <tbody> 
            <tr>
                <th>head1</th>
                <th>head2</th>
                <th>head3</th>
                <th>head4</th>
                <th>head5</th>
                <th>head6</th>
                <th>head7</th>
            </tr>

            <a href="#">
                <tr>
                    <td>col1</td>
                    <td>col2</td>
                    <td>col3</td>
                    <td>col4</td>
                    <td>col5</td>
                    <td>col6</td>
                    <td>col7</td>
                </tr> 
             </a>

        </tbody>

    </table>
</div>
```

I have got this html page and i need to make the entire row as an anchor tag so when i hover over the row and click it I can goto another page. But When i try to execute it, the DOM throws the anchor tag outside table tags and it does not work. How can i implement this ?

Comment: Having `<a>` tag around `<tr>` makes it `Invalid` markup..

Comment: You can put anchor tag for each <td> like : <td><a href="#">col1</a></td>

Comment: Yea, but how do i make the row as an anchor ? is it not possible at all ?

Comment: That won't be semantic, but you could tag the `table` using `div` (or, more accurate, using `ul` since it's a list of rows) and use CSS to display like a `table`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't add `<a>` tag in a `<table>`.
You can only add content in `<td>` tag.

Try to add a `onclick` attribute with `document.location.href+='#anchor'; return false;`

**Example**

```css
table {
  height:200px;
 }

#test{
  height:400px;
  background-color:grey;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr onclick="document.location+='#test';return false;">
    <td>
      click
    </td>
    <td>
      click
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<div class="test" id="test"></div>
```

**Update**

For go to another page use

```
window.location.href="url";
```

instead of

```
document.location
```

Comment: how do i make it to go to another page ? say to google.com ?

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

A link can exist inside a table cell or completely contain a table. There are no options in between.

You could put a link in the first cell and then apply some JavaScript:

```
jQuery("tr").on("click", function (e) {
    location = jQuery(this).find("a").attr("href");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not a valid standard. You can use JS for acnchor. For example:

```
$('.table-bordered tr td').on("click", function(){
  window.location.href= $(this).parent().attr('href');
});
```

TR defination can be:

```
<tr href="http:/www.yahoo.com">.....</tr>
```

Comment: `tr` definition should be `data-href` since `href` is not a valid `tr` attribute

Comment: It was just a reference. Anyway it's not a problem at all but using data-* is good.

Comment: Muhammed Imran Hussain is right. use data attribute of HTML5.